# Azure Bicep - Subresource reference with resourceId()

Tags: azure, templates

I am deploying an App Gateway on Azure using a Bicep template (relevant pieces shown below).

```
var applicationGatewayId = resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', applicationGatewayName)
resource applicationGateway 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2021-08-01' = {
  properties: {
    urlPathMaps: [
      {
        properties: {
          defaultBackendAddressPool: {
            id: '${applicationGatewayId}/backendAddressPools/backendpool-test'
          }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is about the `id` of the backendAddressPool in the example. I get a warning when compiling: `Warning use-resource-id-functions: If property "id" represents a resource ID, it must use a symbolic resource reference, be a parameter or start with one of these functions: extensionResourceId, guid, if, reference, resourceId, subscription, subscriptionResourceId, tenantResourceId. [https://aka.ms/bicep/linter/use-resource-id-functions]`.

- I tried using `${applicationGateway.id}/backendAddressPools/backendpool-test`, but that results in a cyclic reference error. For other resource types I used `resourceId()`, but for this example I wouldn't know how to.
- I tried, e.g., `resourceId('Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool', '${prefix}-backendpool-infocat')`, but that seems to result in a different resource type altogether (doesn't compile into the same id, at least).

This question is applicable to other subresources too, such as:

- `applicationGateway.urlPathMaps.defaultBackendAddressPool`
- `applicationGateway.urlPathMaps.pathRules.backendAddressPool`
- `applicationGateway.urlPathMaps.pathRules.backendHttpSettings`
- ...

So how does one refer to these subresources properly, when there's no readily defined resourceType to be used in `resourceId()`? Can the warnings be avoided?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
id:resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', applicationGatewayName, applicationGatewayBackendAddressPoolName)
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you very much. Do you have any idea where this is documented (I can only find examples that use this path, not the explanation of it)? Or is it common sense and does this type of resourceType path work for any of the possible subresources in the schema?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Here you go, the quickstarts are a good resource if you get confused by the template reference (like I do, often!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI